# Trying to install openssh-client openssh-server on WSL but going through snap error

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, openssh

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-client openssh-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libfwupdplugin1 squashfs-tools
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  openssh-sftp-server ssh-import-id
Suggested packages:
  keychain libpam-ssh monkeysphere ssh-askpass molly-guard
E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true: Success
E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true: Success
```

Also sudo apt auto remove gives the same error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true: Success
E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true: Success
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what causes this `snap` problem, but if you're not going to use snap, I suggest removing snap integration from `apt`:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20snapd.conf
```

You can find related issues [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4640).

Comment: Worked for me Thanks!